# Does anybody have a patch or a kludge trick so that I am able to cross-compile climm-0.6.4 with gnutls-2.12.5?

Tags: linux, security, makefile, cross-compiling, autotools

I am trying to cross-compile [climm-0.6.4](http://www.climm.org/source/climm-0.6.4.tgz) to windows under Ubuntu with the following command:

**./configure --host=i686-pc-mingw32 --enable-ssl=gnutls**

and I get this error message:

```
**checking for libgnutls-config... no
checking for libgnutls - version >= 0.8.8... no
*** The libgnutls-config script installed by LIBGNUTLS could not be found
*** If LIBGNUTLS was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the LIBGNUTLS_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to libgnutls-config.**
```

After some research on the Internet I found a hint [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=529906):

> The package's ./configure script is trying to invoke libgnutls-config
>   and/or libgnutls-extra-config to search for the gnutls library. Newer
>   versions of gnutls do not ship these scripts anymore.

and I am using **gnutls-2.12.5**

Does anybody have a patch or a kludge trick so that I am able to cross-compile climm-0.6.4 with gnutls-2.12.5?

Thank you in advance!

cheers

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the **--with-libgnutls-prefix=PFX** option to the **configure** script telling where the library is.

Other option in to set the environment variable LIBGNUTLS_CONFIG to a program that outputs just the parameters you need to compile/link the library.

Update:
Try the following script, name it mygnutls_config:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "--version" ]
then
    shift
    EXTRA="--modversion"
else
    EXTRA=""
fi
pkg-config gnutls $EXTRA "$@"
```

And then

```
$ chmod a+x mygnutls_config
$ LIBGNUTLS_CONFIG=`pwd`'/mignutls_config' ./configure --enable-ssl=gnutls
```

note that for this to work you need **pkg-config** to detect the crosscompilation configuration, not the native one. So you may need the **PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR** environment variable to point to the directory where the appropriate **gnutls.pc** file is.